# Bind an object attribute to a method

Tags: python, properties

This is a basic Python question. Long ago I saw something like this and I believe it was in Python. Is it possible, or am I wrong?

*I am asking for a way to do this; the example below is just imaginary code of how it could work, but doesn't.*

```
class SomeClass:
    def someMethod(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.id

    name = 'A name'
    id = '37'
    fullClassName = someMethod  # reading this attribute would actually call the method
```

```
>>> a = SomeClass()
>>> print a.fullClassName  # no parentheses as it's not a method call
A name 37
```

Comment: *Is it possible* what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Why did you not just try it? Functions are just objects too, so you *can* add another name that is an alias, yes.

Comment: I tried like this but it didn't work of course, I am asking if there is a _correct way_ to do this or if it is not possible at all. Don't downvote if you don't get the question.

Comment: When it is called like `a = SomeClass() a.fullClassName` it returns 
`<bound method SomeClass.someMethod of <__main__.SomeClass instance at 0x7fd30ea9afc8>>`. I want that there will be no need for the parenthesis to call like a method, but like an attribute.

Comment: I think you want a "property".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

```
>>> class SomeClass:
...     name = 'A name'
...     id = '37'
...
...     @property
...     def someMethod(self):
...         return self.name + ' ' + self.id
...
...     fullClassName = someMethod
...
>>> a = SomeClass()
>>> print a.fullClassName
A name 37
>>>
```

or simply

```
>>> class SomeClass:
...     name = 'A name'
...     id = '37'
...
...     @property
...     def fullClassName(self):
...         return self.name + ' ' + self.id
...
>>> a = SomeClass()
>>> print a.fullClassName
A name 37
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about this, I will read more about properties. It's always good to ask and learn, even if I will get down voted.